# Magento2: how to list categories in static block?

Tags: magento2, category, static-block

How can I list subcategories of some category in a static block?

UPDATE: [It seems there already is a widget available for this in Github](https://github.com/emizentech/magento2-category-list-widget)

Comment: Not compatible with the PHP version I have to run 2.3.1

Answer (score 1):

Mukesh Chapagain has a great tutorial on this. You might need to adapt some things, but this should help.

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-parent-category-children-categories-product-count/

This is how I did it.

```
    public function getCategory($categoryId) 
    {
        $this->_category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
        $this->_category->load($categoryId);        
        return $this->_category;
    }
public function getAllChildren($asArray = false, $categoryId = false)
    {
        if ($this->_category) {
            return $this->_category->getAllChildren($asArray);
        } else {
            return $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getAllChildren($asArray);
        }
    }
     public function getStoreCategories($sorted = false, $asCollection = false, $toLoad = true)
    {
        return $this->_categoryHelper->getStoreCategories($sorted, $asCollection, $toLoad);
    }
        public function getTotalProductCount($categoryId)
        {
            $totalCount = 0;
            $categoriess = $this->getStoreCategories(true, false, true);
            $babies = $this->getAllChildren(true, $categoryId);
            foreach($babies as $babe){
                $babeDetails = $this->getCategory($babe);
                $totalCount = $babeDetails->getProductCount() + $totalCount;
            }

            return $totalCount;
        }
```

Instead of returning the count you could return the names or whatever would apply to you.